# Table Views Loading Wrong Data and Causing Application to Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, restkit

I am working on an application that involves multiple table views.  The application uses a navigation controller and I have a storyboard set up to handle the transitions.  I currently have two of those views set up, one for "Regions" with objects of type "Region" and another for "Categories" with objects of type "Category."  In the code for each view, I use RestKit to load the appropriate data into an array, then use that array of data to create the table.  Each view works fine on its own, if viewed first.  However, when I transition to one view, dismiss it, and attempt to move to the other view, my application crashes.  The exception that is shown suggests that the wrong type of data is being loaded into the array for the table.  For example, if I go to the Categories view first, then switch to the "Regions" view, the application seems to thing that my "Regions" array contains objects of type "Category."  Has anyone else had the issue of data for tables getting mixed up?  How might one solve this problem?  Thanks.

*Edit -- Here is the code for loading the data into the table cells, along with some clarification.*

Each table does contain the correct data if it is the first table to be loaded.  It is only when switching to the other table view that the crash occurs.  The exceptions have been commented into the code where they occur.  "categoryName" and "regionName" are properties of their respective types.

**Regions:**

At the top, I create the array regions:

```
@interface RegionListingsController () {
    NSArray *regions;
}
```

Restkit onDidLoadObjects Method:

```
loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
    NSLog(@"Objects Loaded");
    regions = nil;
    regions = objects;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
};
```

Create Table Cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Region *region = [[Region alloc] init];
    region = nil;
    region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"region");
    cell.textLabel.text = region.regionName; // Exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Category regionName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xce87240'

    return cell;
}
```

Categories:

This is roughly the same, just with a categories array instead of a regions array.
Array:
    @interface CategoryListingsController () {
        NSArray *categories;
    }

onDidLoadObjects:

```
loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
    NSLog(@"Objects Loaded");
    categories = objects;
    objects = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
};
```

Table Cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Category *category = [[Category alloc] init];
    category = nil;
    category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Category Cell");
    cell.textLabel.text = category.categoryName; // Exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Region categoryName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xce87240'
    NSLog(@"Cell returned");

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are your tables loading the correct data on launch? Are you sure your tableviews' datasources are not getting mixed up?

Comment: We'll most definitely need to see some code about how the tableviews are being initialized.

Comment: I just added some code and more details.  The correct data is being loaded into each table, as long as it is the first table viewed.  For example, if I look at the Regions view, all of my regions are there, but the app crashes when I go the the Categories view.  A similar situation happens when I look at Categories first.  The correct data is there, but the app crashes when I go the other view.

Comment: I'd try putting the line `NSLog(@"Objects: %@", objects);` right before `regions = objects;` and the same where you assign to `categories` just to see what is being stored.  If the content isn't correct for the second view, then you would need to track down what's making the load request.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  After using NSLog(@"Objects: %@", objects), if I open the Categories view, then go to the Regions view, the regions array is populated by objects of type Category.  The number of objects is correct, but they are being loaded as the wrong type.  Perhaps it has something to do with how my RestKit mappings are working?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are retaining the objects. Here:

```
regions = objects;
```

And here:

```
categories = objects;
```

You can create yourself some `@properties (nonatomic, retain)` to `regions` and `categories` and then:

```
self.regions = objects;
```

and,

```
self.categories = objects;
```

Also, care with the order you do this:

```
regions = nil;
regions = objects;

categories = objects;
objects = nil;
```

if you go with the `@properties` approach you don't need to `nil` the previous value. Also no need to do this (event with the `@properties`):

```
self.categories = objects;
objects = nil;
```

Just remove the second line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I am still having the problem.  It seems that my RestKit mapping is loading my data as the wrong type, though I'm still investigating how to fix that.